# Passar variável Jquery para PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Estou com este script que traz a geolocalização do usuário:

```js
(function() {

if(!!navigator.geolocation) {

 var map;

 var mapOptions = {

 };
 
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_canvas'), mapOptions);

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
 {  
  var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var php_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var php_longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  alert(php_latitude);
 });
 
} else {
 document.getElementById('google_canvas').innerHTML = 'No Geolocation Support.';
}

})();
```

```html
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=XXX"></script>
```

Preciso passar os valores da latitude e longitude para variáveis no PHP.

Tentei fazendo:

```
<?php 
  $variavelphp = "<script>document.write(php_latitude)</script>";
  echo "Olá $variavelphp";
?>
```

Mas não deu certo.

É possível passar os valores Jquery para PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa enviar via Ajax (chamada do Javascript). Entenda que ao executar javascript no navegador você está "desconectado" do servidor.

Portanto, necessitará de um script PHP no lado servidor para receber e tratar as coordenadas.

Para fazer isso com jQuery, um exemplo seria, após pegar as coordenadas:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "caminho-para-script.php",
   data: { lat: php_latitude, long: php_longitude }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
       // resposta do servidor
       alert( msg );
});
```

E um possível script PHP

```
<?php
    $lat  = $_POST['lat'];
    $long = $_POST['long'];

    // comandos para salvar os dados

    // exemplo de resposta
    echo "Latitude " . $lat . " e Longitude " . $long . " recebidas.";
```

Note que é um exemplo simples que demonstra a conversação (troca de dados) entre cliente (navegador) e servidor (seu código em PHP).