# Passar valores de inputs para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, get

Eu tenho dois inputs, um preenchido automaticamente por um script PHP, e o outro o usuario entra com o valor, e um terceiro input para fazer o calculo de subtração ou adição dos dois primeiros inputs.

Criei os seguintes tópicos:

[Somar valores de dois inputs e mostrar em terceiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212357/somar-valores-de-dois-inputs-e-mostrar-em-terceiro)

https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/559242-somar-valores-de-dois-inputs-e-mostrar-em-terceiro/#comment-2231252

Esses dois tópicos criei para tentar realizar o calculo direto com jquery.
Mas acabei vendo que os valores passados pelo PHP, do primeiro `input`, estão interferindo no cálculo com jQuery. Quando eu dava `alert` no primeiro `input` ele retornava um alert escrito: '*undefined*'

Então pensei em passar os valores dos dois inputs para um script PHP e realizar o cálculo por lá, e então mostrar o resultado em uma tereira DIV

Mas com o código jQuery que montei não estou conseguindo passar os valores, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Ja pesquisei e também achei um artigo sobre:

[Passar variável Jquery para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207392/passar-vari%C3%A1vel-jquery-para-php)

Mas não consegui resolver.

Com o código que fiz, eu queria o var_dump do php aparecendo no terceiro input.

Ficou assim o HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="formvalor">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Valor <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="valor_total">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="valor" id="valor" value="10" readonly><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Entrada <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="valEntrada">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="0"><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Saldo <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="saldo_total">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="saldo" id="saldo" value="" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

O jQuery para passar os valores (Pode ser tanto GET com POST, pra mim nao faz diferença):

```
    $("#entrada").change(function(){
  $.post("saldo_total.php",
  {entrada:''+$("#entrada").val()+'', valor:''+$("#valor").val()+''},
  function(valor){
    $("#saldo").html(valor);
  });
});
```

E o PHP:
    `var_dump($_POST);`

Esta foi a solução que achei para realizar o cálculo, mas se alguém souber de outra em que eu consiga realizar o cálculo sem que os valores PHP interfira no jQuery pode dizer.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

---------------- EDIÇÃO ----------------

Agora o jQuery esta assim:

```
$("#entrada").change(function(){
    $.post("saldo_total.php",
    {entrada:''+$("#entrada").val()+'', valor:''+$("#valor").val()+''},
        function(valor){
            $("#saldo").val(valor);
        });
});
```

E o PHP:

`print_r($_POST);`

E com isso, no input, aparece o array do $_POST assim:

```
Array( [entrada]=>50 [valor]=>undefined )
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "valores do PHP interfiram no jQuery"?

Comment: Isso: [valor] => undefined

Quando pego o valor do input, ele retorna undefined ao invés de vir o valor mesmo, mas isso somente no campo em que o PHP popula

Comment: Já tentou fazer `$("#saldo").val(valor)` no lugar de `html`?

Comment: Quando eu tiro o PHP daquele campo, e deixo um input comum (em que o usuario preenche), aí sim o jquery pega a informação que esta nele

Comment: Com .val() ao invés de .html() ele nao preenche a div que quero

Comment: Você não está preenchendo uma div, mas sim um input.

Comment: Veja se é desta forma que você diz: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/db04466e001795c14b444b302a10f7ca

Comment: Desta forma o valor de saldo não é atualizado para o retorno do PHP?

Comment: No PHP eu chamo o $_POST dentro de um print_r. Então no input ele retorna o campo de entrada no qual eu digitei, e no campo de valor ele continua como undefined

Comment: Então edita a pergunta, coloque o código PHP e esta mensagem do `print_r` que você citou, porquê até agora nada está fazendo sentido.

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria com javascript dessa forma passando colocando o onchange no input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="0" onchange="MUDAVALOR(this.id)">
```

e na função javascript:

```
<script>
function MUDAVALOR(id) {
    var entrada = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var valor = document.getElementById('valor').value;
    entrada = entrada.replace(/\./g,'');
    entrada = entrada.replace(',','.');
    entrada = new Number(entrada);
    valor = valor.replace(/\./g,'');
    valor = valor.replace(',','.');
    valor = new Number(valor);  
    var total = valor + entrada;
    total = total.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('saldo').value = total;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Tentei desse jeito mas a soma nao é realizada, o campo saldo nem se preenche com valor algum

Comment: Da forma que passei funciona perfeitamente, crie uma tela com somente seu html (com os 3 inputs que você passou aqui) e a função em javascript, teste pois funciona, deve ter faltado alguma coisa, você testou com o seu JQuery na página também?, porque tem que tirar nesse caso

Answer (score 0):

Isso provavelmente resolve seu problema, verifique o que é passado como valor para o input `valor` pelo seu código `php`.

```js
(($) => {

  let correctValue = (elementId) => {
    //Javascript não reconhece valores com ',' como floats
    let elem = $('#' + elementId);
    elem.val(elem.val().replace(',', '.'));

  }

  $(document).ready(() => {
    correctValue('valor');

    $('#entrada').on('input', function() {
      correctValue('entrada');

      let valor = parseFloat($('#valor').val()),
        entrada = parseFloat($('#entrada').val()) || 0;

      $('#saldo').val(valor + entrada);

    })
    
  })

})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="formvalor">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Valor <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="valor_total">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="valor" id="valor" value="10" readonly><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Entrada <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="valEntrada">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="0"><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Saldo <small>(R$) </small><span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="saldo_total">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 decimal" name="saldo" id="saldo" value="" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```