# Como guardar variáveis geradas com Jquery no php?

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um botão que adiciona inputs `onclick` e eu gostaria de conseguir guardar ou efetuar o código desejado nalgum `for` para inserção na base de dados.

Este é o código `onclick`

```
$("#add_iframe").click(function(){
    var lengt = $('.thumb').length;
    var tao = lengt + 1;
    $("#list_iframes").append('<label>Iframe '+tao+'</label><input type="text" placeholder="Insira o Iframe do Youtube Aqui" class="form-control thumb" name="iframe" />');
})
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar variável Jquery para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207392/passar-vari%c3%a1vel-jquery-para-php)

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino Veja a minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281570/79646), lá esclareço a minha dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minha dúvida era em pegar nos valores com o nome `iframe` com `$_POST['iframe']` pois todos tinham esse nome. A minha solução baseou-se em guardá-los num `array` pondo os inputs assim:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Insira o Iframe do Youtube Aqui" class="form-control thumb" name="iframe[]" />
```

Com o `iframe[]` consegui pegar nos valores e fiz um simples `for` em php para inseri-los 1 a 1 na base de dados:

```
$count = count($_POST['iframe']);
for($i=1;$i < $count;$i++){
    $insert=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tabela(iframe) VALUES ('".$_POST['iframe'][$i]."')");
}
```